# HTML Polygon is trought menu

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two problems. First I dont know how to hide polygon witch is over my menu when i move page how to hide that polygon under menu ??

Second how to delete that beige color witch is at class "textbox" but under polygon.

First problem at higher image and second at lower image.

http://leteckaposta.cz/701600391  ( Link with image... I cant add images without 10 reputation. )

Style

```css
.textbox {
  text-align: center;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
  .svg--lg {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .svg--sm {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="textbox">
  <div class="big">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</div>
  <div class="small">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon class="svg--sm" fill="white" points="0,0 30,100 65,21 90,100 100,75 100,100 0,100"/>
          <polygon class="svg--lg" fill="white" points="100,0 50,50 0,0 0,0 100,0" />
      </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)